# Loops and Collatz Conjecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a problem with loops and declaring variables. currently I am making a program about Collatz Conjecture, the program should check what is the biggest steps to reach one from certain amount of Collatz Sequence. here's my code :

```
start_num = int(input("insert a starting Number > "))
how_many = int(input("how many times you want to check? >"))


def even_or_odd(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return 'isEven'
    else:
        return 'notEven'


def collatz(n):
    z = n
    counter = 0
    while True:
        if n != 1:
            if even_or_odd(n) == 'isEven':
                n = n/2
                counter += 1
                continue
            if even_or_odd(n) == 'notEven':
                n = (n*3)+1
                counter += 1
                continue
        else:
            print('number ' + str(z) + ' reached 1 with : ' + str(counter) + ' steps')
            return counter
            break


def check_biggest_steps(steps_before, steps_after):
    if steps_before > steps_after:
        return steps_before
    if steps_after > steps_before:
        return steps_after
    if steps_after == steps_before:
        return steps_after


def compute_collatz(n_times, collatz_number):
    for _ in range(n_times):
        before = collatz(collatz_number)
        collatz_number += 1
        after = collatz(collatz_number)
        collatz_number += 1
        biggest_steps = check_biggest_steps(before, after)

    print('Biggest Steps is :' + str(biggest_steps))


compute_collatz(how_many, start_num)
```

this `biggest_steps` variable always return the last 2 steps. I know what causing this problem is that `biggest_step` variable located inside the loop but I can't get it working anywhere don't know what to do. Thanks

Comment: Your `even_or_odd` function is rather.. well, odd. It would be more normal to name it `even` or maybe `is_even`, and have it return either `True` or `False`, so the calling code can do `if is_even(n):`. And if you do it that way, its a one-liner - no need for the `if` statement, just `return not n % 2` - so you might decide to do away with the function, and just use *that* condition in `collatz`. Similarly, you can replace the whole `check_biggest_steps` function with `max(before, after)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read my code until you have tried it yourself.

Try to make a list that appends every change to a list, then to get the number of moves at the end, just get the length of the list.

.

```
def collatz(x):
    while x != 1:
        if x % 2 > 0:
             x =((3 * x) + 1)
             list_.append(x)
        else:
            x = (x / 2)
            list_.append(x)
    return list_


print('Please enter a number: ', end='')
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input())
        list_ = [x]
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invaid selection, try again: ', end='')


l = collatz(x)

print('\nList:', l, sep=' ')
print('Number of steps required:', len(l) - 1)
```

Comment: ok I cheated and look at your code. actually that exception handling just came to my mind after I post this (yeah I write this just after I wake up), and I don't even realize that `list` such a good tool for this. Thank You !

Comment: No problem, just take another look at the code, I've cleaned it up a little.

Comment: Wtf, that's terrible - OP had great idea to keep only the length of the sequence -  uses only log(len(list_)) of memory. And using global variables is gonna kick you hard later.

Comment: What's terrible about it? It's showing a way to think about it and visualise what its doing. You can just use a count, wrap it in a function. You're being overly pedantic, it's not going in a code base, he's learning the language..

Answer (score 1):

you didn't save your biggest_steps and compared always the last 2 only.

I would suggest following change.

```
def compute_collatz(n_times, collatz_number):
    biggest_steps = 0
    for _ in range(n_times):
        steps = collatz(collatz_number)
        if steps > biggest_steps:
            biggest_steps = steps
        collatz_number += 1

    print('Biggest Steps is :' + str(biggest_steps))
```

Comment: that would be wrong. this steps would have the collatz number instead.