# hailstone program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to write a hailstone program in python

you pick a number, if it's even then half it, and if it's odd then multiply it by 3 and add 1 to it. it says to continue this pattern until the number becomes 1.

the program will need methods for the following:

- accepting user input
- when printing the sequence, the program should loop until the number 1.
- print a count for the number of times the loop had to run to make the sequence.

here's a sample run:

prompt (input)

```
Enter a positive integer (1-1000). To quit, enter -1: 20
20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
The loop executed 8 times.

Enter a positive integer (1-1000). To quit, enter -1: 30
30 15 46 23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
The loop executed 19 times.

Enter a positive integer (1-1000). To quit, enter -1: -1
Thank you for playing Hailstone.
```

right now i have this:

```
count = 0
def hailstone(n):
    if n > 0
       print(n)
    if n > 1:
       if n % 2 == 0:
          hailstone(n / 2)
       else:
          hailstone((n * 3) + 1)
    count = count + 1
```

i don't know what to do after this

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431763/loops-and-collatz-conjecture help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think in a modular way, make two functions: check_number() and user_call(). Check_number will verify if the current number in the loop is odd or even and the user_call() just wraps it to count how many times the loop did iterate.

I found the exercise in a great book called Automate Boring Stuff with Python, you have to check it out, if you don't know it already.

Here's my code. Try to use what serves you the best.

```
from sys import exit


def check_number(number):
    
    if number % 2 ==0:
        print(number // 2)
        return(number // 2)
    else:
        print(number*3+1)
        return number*3+1

def user_call(number):
    count = 0
    while number != 1:
        count += 1
        number = check_number(number)
    return count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    try:
        number = int(input('Give a number \n'))
        count = user_call(number)
        print('count ',count)

    except Exception as e:
        exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used recursion to solve the problem.
Heres my code:

Edit: All criteria met

```
count = 0
list_num = []

def input_check():
    number = int(input("Enter a positive integer (1-1000). To quit, enter -1: "))
    if number >= 1 and number <= 1000:
        hailstone_game(number)
    elif number == -1:
        return 
    else:
        print("Please type in a number between 1-1000")
        input_check()

def hailstone_game(number):
    global count
    while number != 1:
        count += 1
        list_num.append(number)
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return hailstone_game(int(number/2))
        else:
            return hailstone_game(int(number*3+1))

    list_num.append(1) # cheap uncreative way to add the one
    print(*list_num, sep=" ")
    print(f"The loop executed {count} times.")
    return

input_check()
```

Additional stuff that could be done:

```
- Catching non-integer inputs using try / except
```

Keep in mind when programming it is a good habit to keep different functions of your code separate, by defining functions for each set of 'commands'. This leads to more readable and easier to maintain code. Of course in this situation it doesn't matter as the code is short.

Answer (score 1):

you can use global
visit https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword to learn more

```
import sys

res = []
def hailstone(number):
    global res
    
    if number > 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            res.append( number // 2 )
            hailstone(res[len(res)-1])
        else:
            res.append(number * 3 + 1) 
            hailstone(res[len(res)-1])

    return res




number = int(input('Enter a positive integer. To quit, enter -1: '))
if number <= 0 or number == 0:
    print('Thank you for playing Hailstone.')
    sys.exit()

else:
    answers = hailstone(number)
    for answer in answers:
        print(answer)
    print('The loop executed {} times.'.format(len(answers) + 1))
```

Comment: format() method insert the specified value in string placeholder --> { }

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function is missing a base/terminating condition so it goes into an infinite loop.

```
resultArray = [] #list

def hailstone(n):
    if n <= 0: # Base Condition
        return
    if n > 0:
       resultArray.append(n)
    if n > 1:
       if n % 2 == 0:
          hailstone(int(n/2))
       else:
          hailstone((n * 3) + 1)

# function call
hailstone(20)
print(len(resultArray), resultArray)
```

Output

```
8 [20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive approach for the problem.

```py
count=0
def hailstone(n):
    global count
    count+=1
    if n==1:
        print(n)
    else:
        if n%2==0:
            print(n)
            hailstone(int(n/2))
        else:
            print(n)
            hailstone(3*n+1)

hailstone(21)
print(f"Loop executed {count} times")
```