# how to return how many times has a recursive function been called in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void funct(int n)
{
    int steps = 0;
    if(n != 1){
        steps++;
        if((n % 2) == 0){
            funct(n/2);
        }
        else if((n % 2) != 0){
            funct((3*n + 1));
        }
        cout << steps << " ";

    }
    
}
```

I tried this code, but it prints 1 in every time; I want my code to print how many times it has ben called.

Comment: Move your `int steps = 0` to the global scope. That or make it a default argument to your function, and simply call `funct(..., steps+1)` each time.

Comment: @Dúthomhas there is no need to use global variables here

Comment: you should be careful with this code. Seems to me like if you call it with an argument `n` equal to 0 you'll get infinite recursion and a stack overflow

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431763/loops-and-collatz-conjecture

Comment: @AlanBirtles For simple problems of the homework variety, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a global to count recursion depth. This kind of thing, even for more serious code, is a _temporary_ monstrosity that is expected to be removed once the code has proven to be working correctly. Don’t waste time and energy otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`steps` is a local variable in `funct` each call to `funct` has its own copy. You need to pass a single variable through all calls to `funct` in order to count correctly.

```
void funct(int n, int& steps)
{
    if(n != 1){
        steps++;
        if((n % 2) == 0){
            funct(n/2, steps);
        }
        else if((n % 2) != 0){
            funct((3*n + 1), steps);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
   int steps = 0;
   funct(5, steps);
   cout << steps << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain please, why shoul i call function by reference of steps variable?

Comment: without a reference it'll be a separate variable for each call

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, the `steps` variable in your function is a local variable of *automatic* storage duration. The latter means that it will be re-initialized to zero on each call of the function.

You can add the `static` keyword to the declaration to make it so that the initialization (to zero) happens only the first time the function is called ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)) and, from then on, the modified value will be maintained across subsequent calls of the function (until or unless it is *explicitly* reset<sup>1</sup>).

However, even with that, if you want to see a 'rolling' count, you will need to put the `cout` line (where the value is reported) **before** you make either of the recursive calls.

Here is a possibility (I have also changed your test condition from `n != 1` to `n > 1`, in order to prevent the potential infinite recursion mentioned in the comments to your question):

```c
void funct(int n)
{
    static int steps = 0; // Initialized only the first time this line is reached
    if (n > 1) {
        steps++;
        std::cout << steps << " ";
        if ((n % 2) == 0) {
            funct(n / 2);
        }
        else if ((n % 2) != 0) {
            funct((3 * n + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> One way to implement this "explicit" reset would be to do so in an `else` block, when the recursion chain is complete. The following code shows how to do this, along with a short `main` that shows how the behaviour works on multiple, sequential 'top-level' calls to `funct`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void funct(int n)
{
    static int steps = 0;
    if (steps == 0) {
        std::cout << "Top-level call with " << n << "... ";
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        steps++;
        std::cout << steps << " ";
        if ((n % 2) == 0) {
            funct(n / 2);
        }
        else if ((n % 2) != 0) {
            funct((3 * n + 1));
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        steps = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    funct(5);
    funct(9);
    funct(8);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Top-level call with 5... 1 2 3 4 5
Top-level call with 9... 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Top-level call with 8... 1 2 3
```

Another way would be to use a 'special' value (like, for example, a negative number) to change the behaviour of the function so that, if such a value is passed, the function resets `steps` to zero and then returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Let the function return how many times it has been called. And that is always one more than the number of calls that the recursive invocation reported:

```
int funct(int n)
{
    int steps = 0;
    if(n != 1){
        if((n % 2) == 0){
            steps = funct(n/2);
        }
        else {
            steps = funct((3*n + 1));
        }
    }
    return steps + 1;
}

int main()
{
   int steps = funct(5);
   cout << steps << "\n";
}
```